# Directly writing account data

Tags: solana-program

I want to write arbitrary account data to an account.

I tried using BPF Loader Upgradeable's Write method, but there was a ton of padding at the start.[image: padding].

Is the only way to do this using an on-chain program? If so, is there an example? I just want to write the 3 bytes [01, 02, 03] to at the start of an account, as a proof of concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the shared memory program
https://spl.solana.com/shared-memory

"A simple program and highly optimized program that writes instruction data into the provided account's data"